# text file didn't show any data with using write file

Tags: python

I run the code and fill in  but my text file does not have the data

my code:

```
def register_patient():
vaccinecenter = input("Your vaccine location in VC1 or VC2?").upper()
while vaccinecenter != "VC1" and vaccinecenter !="VC2":
    print("Please only insert VC1 or VC2")
    vaccinecenter = input("Your vaccine location in VC1 or VC2?").upper()

patientname = name()
patient_id = patientid()
age,vaccine= checkageformvaccine()
phonenumber=contact_number()
medicalhistory = patient_information()
patientdetail = [patientname, patient_id, age , phonenumber,medicalhistory,vaccine, vaccinecenter]
patientlist=[]

with open("patient record.txt","a"):
    for counter in range(0):
        patientlist = []
        dt = input("patient_id: ")
        dn = input("age: ")
        fc = input("vaccine center")

        patientlist.append(dt)
        patientlist.append(dn)
        patientlist.append(fc)
        print(",".join(str))
        patientlist.append(patientdetail)

    print("Record Added Succesfully.")
print("Redirect to menupage")
menupage()
```

how to fix it??
the output data should have written in text

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question it should have no more code than the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem by copy-pasting, a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You're opening the file, `print`ing to standard output, then closing the file. The `with` construct does not redirect standard output to the file. There must be a gazillion examples of how to write to files online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not really sure what content you want to write and in what fashion.
But have a sample snippet below.

```
def register_patient():
    vaccinecenter = input("Your vaccine location in VC1 or VC2?").upper()
    while vaccinecenter != "VC1" and vaccinecenter !="VC2":
        print("Please only insert VC1 or VC2")
        vaccinecenter = input("Your vaccine location in VC1 or VC2?").upper()
    
    patientname = name()
    patient_id = patientid()
    age,vaccine= checkageformvaccine()
    phonenumber=contact_number()
    medicalhistory = patient_information()
    patientdetail = [patientname, patient_id, age , phonenumber,medicalhistory,vaccine, vaccinecenter]
    patientlist=[]
    
    with open("patient record.txt","w") as fp:
        for counter in range(0):
            patientlist = []
            dt = input("patient_id: ")
            dn = input("age: ")
            fc = input("vaccine center")
    
            patientlist.append(dt)
            patientlist.append(dn)
            patientlist.append(fc)
            fp.write(str(dt))
            fp.write(str(dn))
            fp.write(str(fc))

            print(",".join(str))
            patientlist.append(patientdetail)
    
    
    
        print("Record Added Successfully.")
    print("Redirect to menupage")
```

Comment: but still can't get the input in the patient record.txt , it doesn't show at txt file

Answer (score 0):

I'm rather sure, your problem is the

`for counter in range(0):`

You are iterating from 0 to 0 exclusive. Therefore, the loop will not be executed and thus, no content written to the file.

So you should either remove this loop at all, or, if you want it to be executed multiple times, change the value given to `range` with something other than 0.